# How to shift elements to the left by 1 in java

Tags: java

```
static void shiftLeftArray(int[] nums) {
    // make change to nums. 
    // Shift the elements to the right by 1 position. left most elements goes to the left most pos.
    int temp = nums[nums.length-1];
    for(int i= nums.length-2;i>=0;i++)
        nums[i+1] = nums[i];
    nums[0] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes when starting out it can help to use pen and paper to trace through your loops to really get an understanding of what you are doing. I think you'll find you don't want to start from the second to last index (and i should be greater than zero so you don't have an exit clause here as you are incrementing)

Comment: Also when starting out it can be helpful to decide on one or two test cases that you are sure you know the answer to.  Like, if you shift left `{1,2}`, you should get `{2}`.  Test that and see what the result is.  Does it work?  If not, why not?  For a very simple case like this using a debugger to see what is going on is very feasible (another good reason to start with one simple test).

Comment: *left most elements goes to the left most pos* in the code comment makes the question less clear. Is a cyclical shift being sought or do values on one end get removed? As much as I would like code to be able to ask the question itself it doesn't quite work that way on planet Earth. A picture might be worth 1000 words but a snippet of code doesn't ask me a question.

Answer (score 0):

If by shift you mean rotate your array by shifting all element to the left or to the right, just use the [`Collections.rotate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int))

> `rotate(List<?> list, int distance)` where distance is the value of the shift.
> Positive distance -> Right shift
> Negative distance -> Left shift

```java
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Collections.rotate(l, 1);
// [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

If you really want to use your `shiftLeftArray()` function, modify your for loop

```java
// from
for(int i= nums.length-2;i>=0; i++)
// to
for(int i= nums.length-2;i>=0; i--)
```

Answer (score -3):

There are 2 shift operators in java.

1. Left shift operator <<
   a. Essentially shift the bits 'n' times to the left.
   b.  It means the number gets increased (by double in every shift operation) .

   ```
    c. m << n means m * 2^n
    d. int m=4;
         int result = m <<3;
         System.out.println(result);
   ```

It will display 32. ( 4*2^3)

2. Right shift operator >>
   a. Essentially shift the bits 'n' times to the right.
   b.  It means the number gets decreased (by half in every shift operation) .

   ```
    c. m >> n means m / 2^n
    d. int m=32;
         int result = m >> 3;
         System.out.println(result);
   ```

It will display 4. ( 32/2^3)

Comment: He wants to shift element of an array, not the bit of an integer

Comment: agree with @thibsc